# Highchart Wordcloud Legend

Tags: highcharts, legend, word-cloud

Unable to render legend in word cloud in highcharts
Refer the jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/znm6f89r/115/

```
 series: [{
    type: 'wordcloud',
    data: profit,
    name: 'Profit',
    color:'blue'
}],

 legend: {
   enabled: "true"
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Set [series.showInLegend](https://api.highcharts.com/ios/highcharts/plotOptions.series.showInLegend) to true - http://jsfiddle.net/5mLjp77r/

Comment: Yeah works fine. Thank you